# Spring Boot and Google Cloud Cloud DataStore

Tags: spring, spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

**Requirement:**
**Spring  boot Application with  datastore(emulator  in  local)  as  DB**

I  am  looking  for  a  sample  spring  boot  application  which  uses **datastore  emulator**  to  execute    basic  **GET**  and  **POST**  methods.

I  am  not  able  to  find  such  an  example  till  now...  can  someone  guide  me  on this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check this [example from google](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-spring-datastore/index.html#0)

For the emulator part you can refer to this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/tools/datastore-emulator)

**Book class**

```
package com.example.demo;
import org.springframework.cloud.gcp.data.datastore.core.mapping.Entity;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;

@Entity(name = "books")
public class Book {

    @Id
    Long id;

    String title;

    String author;

    int year;

    public Book(String title, String author, int year) {
            this.title = title;
            this.author = author;
            this.year = year;
    }

    public long getId() {
            return this.id;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
            return "Book{" +
                            "id=" + this.id +
                            ", title='" + this.title + '\'' +
                            ", author='" + this.author + '\'' +
                            ", year=" + this.year +
                            '}';
    }
}
```

**BookRepository interface**

```
package com.example.demo;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.cloud.gcp.data.datastore.repository.DatastoreRepository;


public interface BookRepository extends DatastoreRepository<Book, Long> {

  List<Book> findByAuthor(String author);

  List<Book> findByYearGreaterThan(int year);

  List<Book> findByAuthorAndYear(String author, int year);

}
```

**Demo app**

```
package com.example.demo;

import java.util.List;

import com.google.common.collect.Lists;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.shell.standard.ShellComponent;
import org.springframework.shell.standard.ShellMethod;

@ShellComponent
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {
  @Autowired
  BookRepository bookRepository;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
     SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
  }

  @ShellMethod("Saves a book to Cloud Datastore: save-book <title> <author> <year>")
  public String saveBook(String title, String author, int year) {
     Book savedBook = this.bookRepository.save(new Book(title, author, year));
     return savedBook.toString();
  }

  @ShellMethod("Loads all books")
  public String findAllBooks() {
     Iterable<Book> books = this.bookRepository.findAll();
     return Lists.newArrayList(books).toString();
  }

  @ShellMethod("Loads books by author: find-by-author <author>")
  public String findByAuthor(String author) {
     List<Book> books = this.bookRepository.findByAuthor(author);
     return books.toString();
  }

  @ShellMethod("Loads books published after a given year: find-by-year-after <year>")
  public String findByYearAfter(int year) {
     List<Book> books = this.bookRepository.findByYearGreaterThan(year);
     return books.toString();
  }

  @ShellMethod("Loads books by author and year: find-by-author-year <author> <year>")
  public String findByAuthorYear(String author, int year) {
     List<Book> books = this.bookRepository.findByAuthorAndYear(author, year);
     return books.toString();
  }

  @ShellMethod("Removes all books")
  public void removeAllBooks() {
     this.bookRepository.deleteAll();
  }
}
```